# Trying to capture Date and time when a specific field in a single record is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had to add the fields Comments and Comments DateTime to a table.  A user would leave comments, and when this was complete, the Comments DataTime is supposed to capture the date and time of the update of the Comments field.  Many examples I've seen track when the entire record updates a datetime field, however I'm looking to capture the datetime only when the specific Comments field is update for that record. How do I go about doing this? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**edit** Getting incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.updateComments 
ON  dbo.tbl_location_history 
/*Check whether column comments has been updated. If column comments has
been changed, update column comments_datetime with getdate().*/
FOR INSERT,UPDATE AS 
/*Use IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() &7) = 7 to see whether column 7 was updated.*/
/*Checking out IF UPDATE(comments) for proper time stamp */
IF UPDATE(comments)
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE dbo.tbl_location_history
SET dbo.tbl_location_history.comments_datetime = GETDATE();
FROM table dbo.tbl_location_history INNER JOIN 
inserted i ON dbo.tbl_location_history.location_id = i.id
END
```

Comment: You can accomplish this with [Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). I would recommend using an instead of trigger so that you can compare the new comments data with the previous comments and only update the datetime field if the comments are different.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm checking out triggers right now (I'm an SQL newbie).

Answer (score 2):

I would create a trigger on sql server. In that trigger test if the comment is different than the old record. You can log the activity anywhere you like using code in the trigger.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading up on Triggers as we speak.  Still new here, will post the result when I finish this.

Comment: See this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx  and search for the string "IF UPDATE (column)". I think it has what you're looking for

Comment: Ok, trying this it gives me a time stamp, but it time stamps every record in the table when the comments are updated for one record. I need it to only time stamp the record that has it's comments updated. This is very close! Thank you!

Comment: inside the trigger there's a special table called 'inserted' that contains the stuff to be updated/inserted. if you're changing a timestamp in the same table then the value there should be changed. When it actually updates then you'll only affect one row. If you're putting it in another table there's a good example on that same page for inserting 'audit' records when values are changed in a table.

Comment: Working on this. I feel like I'm close.  Still wrapping my head around the concept of inserted and how it works.  I'll see what I can come up with. There are some examples out there, however I'm finding them a little confusing due to not being fully versed in the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track when ONLY the comments field is updated you can use the COLUMNS_UPDATED() function in your update trigger. It can be used to track if column 1, 4, and 6 were updated, or it can track if only column 10 was updated. The code to put inside your trigger will look something like this:

```
IF CAST(SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),1,1) AS INT) = 0)
BEGIN
    --do something here
END
```

It's kind of confusing, but it basically checks which columns were updated and uses binary (I think) to denote what columns were actually changed. Please read through this MSDN article and let me know if you have specific questions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx

Comment: Here is what I have so far: 

    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[updateComments] 
        ON  [dbo].[tbl_location_history] 
        AFTER UPDATE AS 
   /*Check whether column comments has been updated. If column comments has
    been changed, update column comments_datetime with getdate().*/
    
    /*Use IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() &7) = 7 to see whether column 7 was updated.*/
    IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() &7) > 0
    BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.tbl_location_history
  SET comments_datetime = GETDATE();
    END
I apologize for the formatting.

Comment: OK, quick question. Do you want to check if ONLY the comments field was updated, or do you not care if other fields were changed? Also, you might want to post that trigger in your OP so everyone can see it formatted correctly. It looks like you're on the right path for the COLUMNS_UPDATED.

Comment: I want to check only the comments column for updates, none of the others. If there is a change, then I just want to grab the current date and time and place them in comments_datetime

Comment: I mean if you want to check that comments was updated and no other field was changed, you would have to do a check to make sure the other columns' values did not change. But if you don't care about other columns then you should be all set with what you already have.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to tracking these changes in your own schema is to configure the database to do it for you. Starting with SQL Server 2008, you can [enable change tracking at the database level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Change tracking is like an index in that it is maintained transparently by SQL Server. Once enabled on a table, a variety of [change tracking functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510744(v=sql.105).aspx) are available that let you inspect what changed and when.

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT! First off, thank you to EVERYONE that posted here. You've been an amazing help directing me in the right direction.  Looked over the code and saw my mistakes (good night's sleep does wonders).  Here's the solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.updateComments 
ON  dbo.tbl_location_history 
/*Check whether column comments has been updated. If column comments has
been changed, update column comments_datetime with getdate().*/
FOR INSERT,UPDATE AS 

/*Use IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() &7) = 7 to see whether column 7 was updated.*/
/*Checking out IF UPDATE(comments) for proper time stamp */
IF UPDATE(comments)
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE dbo.tbl_location_history
SET dbo.tbl_location_history.comments_datetime = GETDATE()
FROM dbo.tbl_location_history INNER JOIN inserted i ON dbo.tbl_location_history.location_id = i.location_id
END
```